# Shell : How to put multiple statements in one line if

Tags: shell, if-statement

I'm facing a little issue with my "IF" tests.

What I want to do :

```
if [[ "$foo" == "TEST" ]]
then
  echo "OK"
else
  echo "KO"
  return 1
fi
```

My first try in one line if :

```
[[ "$foo" == "TEST" ]] && echo "OK" || echo "KO"; return 1
```

But the return is applied either if the test is right or wrong.

Second try :

```
[[ "$foo" == "TEST" ]] && echo "OK" || (echo "KO"; return 1)
```

The return 1 is executed, but does not exit my function. I've found that the brackets are interpreted as a sub-shell.

I have no idea how to do what I want to do. Is that even possible ?

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Comment: Use curly braces, not parens. And don't use `foo && bar || baz` as if it were a ternary statement; it's not. Use `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi` -- it's longer, but the former can run `baz` even if `foo` was true, should `bar` fail.

Comment: ...which is to say -- the original, longer code was correct. If you want to make it a one-liner, add `;`s as line separators.

Comment: ...for the narrow "how do I do grouping without creating a subshell?", that's what `{ echo "KO"; return 1; }` is for.

Comment: Hello Charles, Thanks for your answers. I don't understand "don't as if it were a ternary statement; it's not". Is that because I have 2 statements in the else part ? When to use   foo && bar || baz   ?

Comment: The only time to use `foo && bar || baz` is if you want `baz` to run if **either** `foo` or `bar` fails. People who use it in places where they expect it to run only if `foo` fails and don't think about the `bar` case are playing with fire.

Comment: See shellcheck warning [SC2015](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015).